# PHP Change name of sender.

Tags: php, forms, email

When the form is submitted I would like to change the name of the sender. Right now it just shows my test domain name as the sender when I get the email.

```
    <?php

    if ($_POST["submit"]) {

         $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Form submitted</div>';

    if (!$_POST['name']) {

        $error="<br />Please enter your name";

    }

    if (!$_POST['email']) {

        $error.="<br />Please enter your email address";

    }

    if (!$_POST['comment']) {

        $error.="<br />Please enter a comment";

    }

    if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

        $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address"; 

   }

    if ($error) {

        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';

    } else {

        if (mail("email@email.com", "Comment from website!", "Name: ".$_POST['name'],."

            Email: ".$_POST['email']."

            Comment: ".$_POST['comment'])) {

                $result='<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank you!</strong> I\'ll be in touch</div>';

                } else {

                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</strong></div>';

                }

        }


    } 


?>
```

Form

```
    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 emailForm">

            <h1>My email form</h1>

            <?php echo $result; ?>

            <p class="lead"> Please get in touch - I'll get back to you as soon as I can.</p>

            <form method="post">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" />

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" />

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="comment">Your Comment:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment"><?php echo $_POST['comment']; ?></textarea>

                </div>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit" />

            </form> 

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is my first contact form, and would really appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
$to      = 'user@example.com';
$subject = 'Comment from website!';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: your_name@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: your_name@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```